# Pandas Categorical data type not behaving as expected

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, ordinal

I have the Pandas (version 0.15.2) dataframe below. I want to make the `code` column an ordered variable of type `Categorical` after the `df` creation as below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                    'code' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                                'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                    'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','code','amount'])

df.code = df.code.astype('category')
>> 0      one
>> 1      one
>> 2      two
>> 3    three
>> 4      two
>> 5    three
>> 6      one
>> 7      two
>> Name: code, dtype: category
>> Categories (3, object): [one < three < two]
```

So this works, but only partially. I cannot impose the order. All functionality below, which are demonstrated on the [documentation webpage](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html#working-with-categories), throw syntax errors for me:

```
df.code = df.code.astype('category', categories=['one','two','three'], ordered=True)
>> error: astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categories'
```

Or even:

```
df.code.ordered
>> error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ordered'
df.code.categories
>> error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'categories'
```

**1)** This is annoying. I cannot even get the categories (levels) of my `Categorical` variable. Am I doing something wrong or is the web documentation out of date/ inconsistent?

**2)** Also, do you know whether the type `Categorical` has a distance notion, i.e. does Pandas know that based on the ordering above, `one` is closer to `two` than `three`? I plan to use this for (dis)similarity calculation.

Comment: The name "Categorical" implies there is no ordering.  If there were an ordering, the data would be ordinal, not categorical.

Comment: Well that is what I thought initially, but if you check the document link I have included, you will see they actually allow ordering.

Comment: Yes, ther is ordering as in ordinal, but not cardinal.  So 'one' is closer to 'two' than 'three', but 'two' is not double the value of 'one'.  Are you sure you don't just want to use an integer here?  If two actually means 2, then you don't want to use a categorical variable.  If you really want categorical here, then any concept of 'distance' is inherently based on sorting.

Comment: Yes, one two are just (probably bad) examples I created for argument's sake. I need ordinal variables.

Comment: Integers are ordinal (in practice)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short example with an ordered categorical variable and (to me) a surprising result from using `rank()` (as a sort of distance measure):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'code':['one','two','three','one'], 'num':[1,2,3,1] }) 
df.code = df.code.astype('category', categories=['one','two','three'], ordered=True)

    code  num
0    one    1
1    two    2
2  three    3
3    one    1

df.sort('code')

    code  num
0    one    1
3    one    1
1    two    2
2  three    3
```

So `sort()` works as expected, in the order specified.  But `rank()` doesn't do what I would have guessed, it ranks lexicographically and ignores the ordering of the categorical variable.

```
 df.sort('code').rank()

   code  num
0   1.5  1.5
3   1.5  1.5
1   4.0  3.0
2   3.0  4.0
```

All of which is perhaps a longer way of asking:  Maybe you just want an integer type?  I mean, you could make up some kind of distance function here post-sorting, but ultimately that's going to be a lot more work than what you could do with a standard int or float (and possibly problematic if you look at how `rank()` handles an ordered categorical.

**edit to add**:  Part of the above may not work for pandas 15.2 but I believe you can still do this to specify order:

```
df['code'].cat.categories = ['one','two','three']
```

What will happen in 15.2 by default (as I understand it) is that ordered will be True by default (but False in version 16.0), but order will be lexicographical rather than as specified in the constructor.  I'm not sure though, and am working in 16.0 so you'll have to just observe how your version behaves.  Remember that Categorical is still fairly new...

Comment: I am using Pandas version 0.15.2, which version are you using? This syntax does not work on my machine: `df.cat.astype('category', categories=['one','two','three'], ordered=True)`. It throws: `error: astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categories'`.

Comment: Yes, I think so.. I think it is just disappointing how unhelpful `pd.Categorical` is at this stage. I am not sure what use cases it can solve as it stands..

Comment: It looks like the ability to use arguments with astype is new in 16.0, but 'm pretty sure you can still do ordered in 15.2.  The docs mention that ordered was the default in 15 and now unordered is the default.

Comment: Unfortunately version 0.15.2 certainly does not recognise either `df.code.ordered` or `df.code.categories`. It just throws the syntax errors in my question.

Comment: I think it needs to be ```df.cat.code.categories```.  I think I may have accidentally chosen a very poor column name in 'cat' (I'll change that).  It looks like you need to use 'cat' like 'str' or 'dt'.

Comment: I tried the syntax as it appears on the web documentation and it just doesn't work... I am giving up on using this, will go with manually converting all ordinals to integers :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can specify an order, [`pd.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.factorize.html) appears to give that option, but it is not implemented, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6926).

Based on what you described, you are looking for coding the `code` variable into an *ordinal* variable, not a *categorical* variable, which are [slightly different](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/whatstat/nominal_ordinal_interval.htm).

If you can assume the difference between `'one'` and `'two'` is equal to that between `'two'` and `'three'`. I guess you can just code them into `int`s `(0, 1, 2, 3 ...)`.

If you use [`patsy`](https://github.com/pydata/patsy), then there is a [nice example for ordinal variables](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/contrasts.html#backward-difference-coding)

Comment: Thank you, Categorical definitely allows order specification. I am more confused on the implementation and syntaxing.