# Pandas Ordinal Variable Treatment in Similarity Calculation

Tags: python, pandas, distance, similarity, categorical-data

I have a Pandas version 0.15.2 dataframe as below with an ordinal column `rate`, represented initially as strings. My end goal is to find the similarities of different rows in the `df` (in reality I have a lot more rows and more ordinal variables).

Currently, to [factorize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) while enforcing the ordering I want, I first convert `rate` to [Categorical](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html), then sort the `df` and finally factorize so `Bad` gets the smallest integer value and `Good` gets the highest. In this fashion I create the `factor_rate` column, which I can then use as a dimension (among others) to calculate similarities / distances. These are given in the code below.

However, I feel this is a memory inefficient and slow hack. What is the fastest and most memory-efficient way to achieve this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                   'rate' : ['bad', 'bad', 'neutral', 'good',
                                'neutral', 'good', 'bad', 'neutral'],
                   'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','rate','amount'])

df.rate = pd.Categorical(df.rate, categories=["bad","neutral","good"], ordered=True)

df = df.sort('rate', ascending=True)
df.loc[:,'factor_rate'] = pd.factorize(df.rate)[0]
```

**Note 1**: This question is linked to my previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829427/pandas-categorical-data-type-not-behaving-as-expected).

**Note 2**: I know that `pandas.factorize()` had an `order` parameter which is now or soon will be deprecated, so I cannot use it directly.

**Note 3**: I am aware of the Gower metric and that ordinal variables should be treated differently to purely numeric ones in similarity calculations, but that is not the point of my question.

Comment: I don't know if this is better but you could remove the sort and do this instead :`df['factor_rate'] = df['rate'].map(dict(zip(["bad","neutral","good"], np.arange(3))))`  define your category list and use this to construct a dict and pass this to `map`

Comment: The thing that the above solves is any worries about order and behaviour wrt to factorize as you are now in charge of the categories and their order

Comment: @EdChum, thank you - and as far as I understand this removes the dependency on `Categorical` as well. Would you mind posting this as an answer. It is just disappointing how unhelpful `pandas.Categorical` is at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned or reliant on categorical then another approach is to define your categories in a list and an order, use this to create a dict to map the order to the categories and pass this dict to [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map):

```
In [560]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                   'rate' : ['bad', 'bad', 'neutral', 'good',
                                'neutral', 'good', 'bad', 'neutral'],
                   'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','rate','amount'])
cat_list = ["bad","neutral","good"]
cat_dict = dict(zip(cat_list, np.arange(len(cat_list))))

df['factor_rate'] = df['rate'].map(cat_dict)
df
Out[560]:
   id     rate    amount  factor_rate
0   1      bad -1.436574            0
1   2      bad  0.210717            0
2   3  neutral -0.896904            1
3   4     good -1.724393            2
4   5  neutral  1.792339            1
5   6     good -1.312713            2
6   7      bad  0.555877            0
7   8  neutral -0.681881            1
```

sorting by the new 'factor_rate' column produces the same output as your current solution:

```
In [562]:

df.sort('factor_rate')
Out[562]:
   id     rate    amount  factor_rate
0   1      bad -1.436574            0
1   2      bad  0.210717            0
6   7      bad  0.555877            0
2   3  neutral -0.896904            1
4   5  neutral  1.792339            1
7   8  neutral -0.681881            1
3   4     good -1.724393            2
5   6     good -1.312713            2
```

**EDIT**

Actually the underlying coding is stored in the Category dtype:

```
In [569]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                   'rate' : ['bad', 'bad', 'neutral', 'good',
                                'neutral', 'good', 'bad', 'neutral'],
                   'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','rate','amount'])
​
df['rate'] = pd.Categorical(df.rate, categories=["bad","neutral","good"], ordered=True)
df['rate'].cat.codes
Out[569]:
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    1
5    2
6    0
7    1
dtype: int8
```

So my answer may not be necessary, the link to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.codes.html#pandas.Series.cat.codes) is empty at the moment.

Comment: It sounds like what you really wanted all along was a labelled integer, and Ed's answer is perfect for that.  That's not really what a categorical variable is though, although it may superficially appear to be.  In some other stats packages you can store something as an integer but display it with labels (which is what Ed's answer does, but takes two columns to do it).  I'm pretty sure you could do that in pandas (not sure how off the top of my head tho)?  It's sort of how indexes work, right?  There is a label and a level, and it's an integer underneath but displays words.

Comment: @JohnE, look for instance at the `daisy` function in R's `cluster` package, you can specify a column as an ordered factor and it is automatically taken into acocunt while calculatnig similarities. `Pandas` has taken the `factor` concept and named it `categorical`, which (similar to factor in R) can be in the form of `ordinal` or `nominal` but they have been merged into one class.

Comment: @EdChum (in case you wanted to do more work...) Could this also be done  easily as a format?  That is, instead of having two columns, store the variable as an integer but display as 'good', 'bad', etc.

Comment: @Zhubarb  Sorry, I don't know much R, but regardless I'm still not sure how you are defining 'similarity' in a quantitative sense.  Ordinal, cardinal, etc.?  0,1,2 and -1,0,1 have the same ordinal ranking but are much different if you multiply and divide, for example.

Comment: Well you should find that with your original code after assigning to 'rate' the categories that you can get the `codes`: `df.rate.cat.codes`, I'll update my answer

Comment: @EdChum  Note that you are (I think) locked into 0,1,2 for values whereas for something like good/neutral/bad you **might** prefer -1,0,1 in comparison to formatted values for an integer.  So I think your original answer remains a more general solution.  But that's just a side comment.  I don't know if that matters here or not as I still am not sure what concept of distance or similarity Zhubarb is looking for.

Comment: @JohnE likert scale. so 0-1-2 is actually more convenient. Sim(netural,good) > Sim(bad, good). EdChum, thanks a lot for your edit. It seems `Categorical` is useful after all. That is actually what I was looking for!